# How can we run a jenkins job through python script with parameters

Tags: python, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

There is a jenkins job which used to run manually by clicking on build with parameters and then add required parameters and click on build. Now we want to auto trigger this job with parameters using python script. Need a python script which can  build the jenkins job with parameters

can we do it with requests.get in python?

Comment: Jenkins has a REST API (https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/using/remote-access-api/) which you can call to trigger jobs using Python (or any other modern programming language). You can use Python's requests, even other packages like httpx, aiohttp, etc. Then, for Python specifically, there are Python-based wrappers around the Jenkins APIs so that you don't need to form the API requests manually: [jenkinsapi](https://pypi.org/project/jenkinsapi/), [python-jenkins](https://pypi.org/project/python-jenkins/), [aiojenkins](https://pypi.org/project/aiojenkins/), etc.

Answer (score 0):

Although you can find the POST request more preferable for build triggering, you can still use the GET request for the same purpose.

First of all, you need to mark your job as the one that can be triggered by scripts.
You can do it by ticking the 'Trigger builds remotely' checkbox in the 'Build Triggers' job configuration section.
This action will force you to create an Authentication Token which will be used as a parameter of your URL.

After this you can GET the following URL via requests lib to trigger a build for your job remotely:
http://**SERVER**/job/**MYJOB**/buildWithParameters?token=TOKEN&PARAMETER=Value

**SERVER** - your server address
**MYJOB** - name of your Jenkins job

So the code may look like the following:

```
import requests

jenkins_url = 'http://your-jenkins-server'
job_name = 'your-job-name'

build_parameters = {
    'token': 'your_auth_token',
    'param1': 'value1',
    'param2': 'value2',
    # Add more parameters as needed
}

build_url = f'{jenkins_url}/job/{job_name}/buildWithParameters'
response = requests.get(build_url, params=build_parameters)
```

If you ara building the parameters clause on your own, then keep in mind that all parameters need to be properly URL-escaped, and parameter name casing is important.

see more details [here](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Build)

**!EDIT!**

For the POST request the code may look like the following:

```
import requests

jenkins_url = 'http://your-jenkins-server'
job_name = 'your-job-name'

build_parameters = {
    'token': 'your_auth_token',
    'param1': 'value1',
    'param2': 'value2'
    # Add more parameters as needed
}

build_url = f'{jenkins_url}/job/{job_name}/buildWithParameters'
response = requests.post(build_url, data=build_parameters)
```

So the difference is in the Content-Type, which makes POST request more secure.

The Jenkins may return HTTP 403 for the POST request with the following Error: "Error 403 No valid crumb was included in the request"

In this case you have to add the 'Jenkins-Crumb' header to your request

```
headers = {
  'Jenkins-Crumb': 'your-crumb'
}

response = requests.post(build_url, data=build_parameters, headers=headers)
```

To get a crumb you need to make a GET request to the http://SERVER/crumbIssuer/api/json URL and store the value of the 'crumb' key from the JSON response.

Comment: in the example you mentioned above token is not used, How to you token and also can you tell how to use POST request.

Comment: yeah, sorry. The token is just a parameter called 'token'. I've edited the answer to make it more clear.
Also, the POST request-related part is added. It may look a little bit cumbersome compared to the GET request, but it's more secure.

Comment: I have added this code but it is giving resp as 403
import requests
from requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions import InsecureRequestWarning
url = "https://xxxx.net:yyyy/job/Common/job/Load%20on%20machin%20using%20tools/build?delay=0sec"
build_params = {'token':'test', 'Machine': 'abc', 'Component_name': 'xyz','Version_name': '123', 'Load_Type':'xxx'}
requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings(InsecureRequestWarning)
resp = requests.post(url,params = build_params, auth=("username", "password"),verify=False)
print(resp.status_code)

Comment: What is the error in the response body?
Is it "HTTP ERROR 403 No valid crumb was included in the request"?
If yes, then you need to add the Jenkins-Crumb header, it is described above

Comment: how to generate a crumb ?

Comment: it's mentioned in the answer:

To get a crumb you need to make a GET request to the http://SERVER/crumbIssuer/api/json URL and store the value of the 'crumb' key from the JSON response.

So you have to make 2 requests: 1st GET to get a crumb, and the 2nd POST to trigger a build with an attached crumb

You can read more about this here https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/security/csrf-protection/